# column-count:2 doesn't work when there are 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I have the below example that work fine for all cases except when the number of divs is 2!

The wanted behavior is to always display divs in 2 columns.

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
</div>
```

This is the behavior I have for more than 2 divs (That I want to preserve):

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
  <div class="square">4</div>
  <div class="square">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reasons these elements need to be `inline-block`? Because if I just remove that, it appears to work fine with just two elements as well?

Comment: Yeah the display: block works perfectly when there are only 2 divs. But not when I have more than 2! You can play with the example I have.

Comment: Remove display, and add `break-inside: avoid;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a specific rule for the case of 2 divs using float:

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  margin:5px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.square:first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
   float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
</div>
```

Even with display:block

```css
.container {
  column-count: 2;
  margin:5px;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.square:first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
  <div class="square">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with `float` is that it's a very outdated method of positioning.

Comment: @expressjs123 I am not using float to position anything. I am using float to trigger a different display and no float is not outdated. It's a CSS property we should keep using when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You put `width: 100%` on each of the elements, which, remember is **relative** to the container. Therefore it can't fit two full width elements and expands them into two rows. Removing that line puts them into two columns. 50% is the upper limit for the width otherwise it can't fit two elements in a row.

Comment: width will take the width of the container /2 because of column-count set to 2

Comment: what did you put for the width?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use css grid you have to adjust your container to allow for two columns. If you have unlimited squares but always want them to break into two columns use flexbox instead

*Flexbox*

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
   width: 50%;
}
```

*Grid*

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">1</div>
  <div class="square">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the flexbox example instead then

Comment: Doesn't work too. I don't have the order I want (column order)

Comment: I dont understand the column order part, here is a codepen for wrapping divs using flexbox https://codepen.io/jmcfarlane/pen/YzWVyGZ

Comment: Copy paste my code in your code pen (or simply just run the snippet in my post) and you'll see the order I'm talking about ( it's from top to bottom)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. All I know is that I'll always have 2 columns

Comment: Ok so you are looking for 2 columns split evenly more or less, but when there is only 2 items it doesnt split correctly I understand now... let me see